# Twilio IOS pod install -> Errno::ETIMEDOUT - Operation timed out - connect(2)

Tags: ios, iphone, twilio

I was trying to install a pod on twilio quick start IOS source code https://github.com/twilio/ip-demo-ios, as they suggest to install it to complete the dependencies.
But it always throws me `Errno::ETIMEDOUT - Operation timed out - connect(2)` error.

Answer (score 0):

Delete your podfile and again create it , edit it by opening with xcode not textedit , then try again

Comment: Done the same thing, still it shows Failed to connect to static.twilio.com port 80: Operation timed out